# who to find and separating a special part of text of in TextBox and copy it in a other TextBox with C#?

Tags: c#

I have a long text in the multi line TextBox . I will seprarating a part of the text that begining with a special word and end with a other special word . so then copy it in a other TextBox .
please help me .

Comment: if the start and end word are a fixex value, you can use regular expressions to filter out the content

Comment: no  the start and end word not are fixex . but can you write the code for fixex value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use regex to resolve this issue.
Below is the codes:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Regex_GetSpecialPart_Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string example = "starttest_exampleend";
            var match = Regex.Match(example, @"start(\S+)end");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var result = match.Result("$1");
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }   
}
```

The result is "test_example"

Answer (score 0):

Try split
Example :

```
string data = "TEXTONExxTEXTTWOxxTEXTTHREExxTEXTFOUR";
return data.Split(new string[] { "xx" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the best choice, but in case you don't want to use it and prefer to write extra code, use this:

```
public String getTextBetween(string start, string end, string text) {
            int t1 = 0;
            int t2 = 0;

            if (text == null) return "";
            t1 = text.IndexOf(start);
            if (t1 >= 0) t2 = text.IndexOf(end, t1 + start.Length);

            return text.Substring(t1 + start.Length, t2 - t1 - start.Length);
        }
```